# Eliminar paquete Nuget que ya no existe en nuget.org

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2022

Alguien de la comunidad sabria como puedo eliminar un paquete nuget que ya no esta disponible.

Ya que me pide restaurar los paquetes, pero estos ya no existen en el origen.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solucion, eliminando las referencias desde el package.config. Ahi ya desaparecerian desde las librerias instaladas en el nuget.